# Please explain this struct usage

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, struct

```
#define MAX_THREADS ( 17 )
struct thread_info
{
  unsigned int * thread_sp; /* Storage space for thread stack-pointer. */
  int thread_id;            /* Storage space for a thread ID. */
};
struct thread_info thread_info_array[ MAX_THREADS ];
```

I don't understand the second struct, can you please explain what it does? How does the constant change the struct if we change the constant?

### Update

I think it's the same as:

```
struct thread_info { unsigned int *thread_sp; int thread_id; } thread_info_array[MAX_THREADS];
```

Comment: Not quite the same, that single version is missing the struct tag.

Comment: @teppic Thank you. `struct thread_info { unsigned into * thread_sp; int thread_id; } thread_info_array[MAX_THREADS];` (?)

Comment: That's almost the same. But here you're defining a variable of unnamed type - you won't be able to use this type anywhere else, e.g. you can't define any more variables of the kind in contrast to the first version.

Comment: @icepack - with the tag present, there's no problem.

Comment: @teppic agree, the question was edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "second struct".

This:

```
struct thread_info
{
  unsigned int * thread_sp; /* Storage space for thread stack-pointer. */
  int thread_id;            /* Storage space for a thread ID. */
};
```

is a **type definition**.

This:

```
struct thread_info thread_info_array[ MAX_THREADS ];
```

is an array definition of MAX_THREADS elements where each element is of type `struct thread_info` that you've defined above.

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
struct thread_info thread_info_array[ MAX_THREADS ];
```

is an array of the previously declared `thread_info` structs. The array consists of `MAX_THREADS` elements; if you change the constant, the size of the array will change.

See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/typedef.html) for why the second `struct` keyword is required.

Answer (score 2):

`struct thread_info thread_info_array[ MAX_THREADS ];` implies `thread_info_array` is an array of `thread_info` structures of `MAX_THREADS` elements.

Changing the constant only changes the number of elements in the array but will not impact the `struct` definition.